# Pig - removing duplicate tuples from bag

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following loaded in a relation with this schema {group: (int,int),A: {(n1: int,n2: int)}}:

```
((1,1),{(0,1)})
((2,2),{(0,2)})
((3,3),{(3,0)})
((4,2),{(1,3)})
((5,1),{(2,3)})
((5,3),{(1,4)})
((7,3),{(2,5)})
((9,1),{(4,5)})
((10,2),{(4,6)})
((10,4),{(7,3)})
((11,1),{(5,6)})
((11,3),{(4,7)})
((12,4),{(4,8)})
((13,1),{(6,7)})
((19,1),{(10,9),(9,10)})
((,),{(,),(,),(,)})
```

I would like to extract just the first tuple from each bag, i.e.:
        ((19,1),{(10,9),(9,10)}) --> (10,9)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like this?.

```
C = FOREACH B {
                top1 = LIMIT A 1;
                GENERATE FLATTEN((top1));
              }
```

here B is your group relation name.